How can "chemical-free" surface cleaners work?
There's a company called 2San that has gotten some press recently for selling a "chemical-free" cleaner, which is "created by re-engineering water in a seven-stage filtration process". It's called Clean Zero.
The marketing materials state:

Clean Zero is produced through microfiltration of water, and provides cleaning and sterilisation to a hospital grade standard. The product is ideal for all daily cleaning tasks on water washable surfaces – the ingredients are naturally derived, making it 100% sustainable.
The seven-stage process begins with the removal of elements such as chlorine, grit, and other inorganic compounds such as calcium that are naturally found in water. The water is then purified in a process that uses a partially permeable membrane to dispose of the unwanted contaminants and molecules before the final stages of hydro-embellishment. The composition of Clean Zero is unstable and therefore it performs a mechanical action when applied to surfaces, enabling it to absorb dirt and contamination. The result is a clean, streak-free surface without any residue.
As Clean Zero eradicates 99% of bacteria and viruses including COVID-19 in two seconds, there is no need for a separate sanitiser to be used.

This product is now being used by a government-owned train operator in the United Kingdom. The company sells the cleaning solution in both bottle form, and manufactures kit that can apparently provide you with an endless supply of it.
Ignoring the fact that water is clearly a chemical compound, I don't understand how this works. Is it just filtered water? What is "hydro-embellishment"?
I was under the impression distilled water wouldn't have any sterilising activity/antimicrobial properties[1], so how is it actually achieving sterilisation?
[1]: Burton, Maxine et al. “The effect of handwashing with water or soap on bacterial contamination of hands.” International journal of environmental research and public health vol. 8,1 (2011): 97-104. doi:10.3390/ijerph8010097

This might be relevant: https://www.totousa.com/tips/what-is-ewater-plus

The relevant buzzword (found somewhere on their site) seems to be "re-engineered water", though it's not clear which type they're using (except it's probably not steam).

Electrolysis may well explain it, though as your site states @Laurel - it's hardly "chemical-free" once the process is complete! It's interesting though, their site doesn't imply you need to add salt to the machines that they sell.. Unless that's what's hidden in the "filters". Is there actually enough sodium in tap water to do this without needing additional salt?

The manufacturer's website link talks about using ATP test for cleanliness. Here is some background information.

@AdamWilliams "it's hardly "chemical-free" once the process is complete!" I think that's the heart of the question. From the link I posted above: "Electrolyzing regular tap water produces a solution of hypochlorous acid and sodium hydroxide" Those sure sound like chemicals to me but earlier in that same page they claim it is "chemical-free". It doesn't seem to make sense from a literal perspective so I'm assuming they mean no chemicals are added.

@JimmyJames don't the previous six stages remove chlorine and sodium? It's not "tap water" by that stage. The chemicals are removed.

A reminder to the linguistic prescriptivists: Scientists don't own words, and the battle over the term "chemical-free" was, perhaps sadly, lost by them a couple of decades ago. When used in marketing, the marketing definition (approximately: "no artificial additives produced in lab conditions by chemical reactions") can be inferred.

Does distilled water have any relevant antimicrobial effects?

Water is H2O, i.e. oxygen and hydrogen, depending on the last steps applied to the 'hydro-embellished' water a whole host of chemically active (and thus potentially cleaning) substances could be produced,H2O2, H2O3, HO, HO3, O2, O3, ... depending on the letter of the law, this might not have to be disclosed, as no material is added - to make those stable would require changing the 2:1 ratio of H:O, which would afaik severly affect pH, and also the drinkability...

Interestingly, in https://www.amazon.co.uk/2San-Clean-Chemical-Surface-Cleaner/dp/B0C737VD75 this product is "plant based".

Comments about linguistic prescriptivism have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Related Meta discussion here.

It's probably not ozone.
Or if it is, they're lying about the shelf life of their product.
Laurel's answer suggests that Clean Zero might be ozonated water, i.e. pure water mixed with small quantities of ozone (O3).  Ozonated water is an actual substance that can be produced on demand from air and purified water and used as a disinfectant.
However, ozone is an unstable and highly reactive substance that decays quite rapidly in water.  Even under ideal circumstances (cold and very pure water) the half-life of ozone in water is only about 30 minutes, meaning that only 50% of the original ozone remains after 30 minutes, only 25% after 1 hour, only 6.25% after 2 hours and so on.  Further, if the water is warmed up to room temperature or contains trace impurities that can react with the ozone, the half-life reduces to just a few minutes.
This is blatantly incompatible with Clean Zero's assertion that their product has an active shelf-life of several months.  In particular, the Clean Zero website's page for their 500 ml plastic "Ready To Use Sprayer" bottles says (emphasis mine):

When required, simply fill directly from your Clean Zero 20, Clean Zero 80 or Clean Zero Hi-Vol unit and use on surfaces such as worktops, mirrors, washroom fittings and touch points. Store away from direct sunlight and your Clean Zero will remain active for a minimum of 10 months.

If Clean Zero is ozonated water, there won't be any detectable ozone left in it after storing it in a plastic bottle for 10 months (or even 10 hours), whether in direct sunlight or not.
It could be hydrogen peroxide.
Dilute solutions of hydrogen peroxide (H2O2) in water are also commonly used as disinfectants and they can be produced from oxygen and water using electricity and a solid catalyst.
While hydrogen peroxide is also unstable and naturally decomposes back into water and oxygen, it is significantly more stable than ozone.  Under ideal conditions dilute hydrogen peroxide may decay by less than 0.5% per year but its decay can be accelerated by various factors, including both high temperature and the presence of catalytic impurities as well as exposure to air and to ultraviolet light (including sunlight).  When stored in an unopened bottle and away from sunlight, commercially available hydrogen peroxide solutions can remain effective for up to 3 years, but opening the bottle and exposing the solution to air can reduce its effective lifetime to just a few months.
Of course, all this depends on both the original composition of the peroxide solution (including whether it contains any chemical stabilizers that slow down the decay), the way it's stored and — last but not least — on what you define the minimum effective concentration of remaining peroxide to be.  Still, just as a random data point, this commercially available 1.4% hydrogen peroxide disinfectant spray is advertised as having a shelf life of 24 months, which is comparable to the 10 month active life advertised for Clean Zero.  The difference between 10 and 24 months may plausibly come down to different initial peroxide concentrations, different storage conditions, different efficacy standards and/or the presence of stabilizer chemicals in the off-the-shelf product.
It might just be water (and snake oil).
All that said, I cannot rule out the possibility that Clean Zero is simply nothing but purified water.  Indeed, their marketing materials seem to go to great lengths to suggest that their product contains nothing but pure "chemical free" water, somehow magically "embellished" to become an effective cleaning agent.
However, it's worth noting that just wiping a dirty surface with clean water (and a clean cloth) can be enough to remove a fairly large fraction of organic contaminants (including viruses, bacteria and other microorganisms) on it, especially if the surface itself is relatively non-porous and the dirt on it is not particularly oily or stuck to the surface.  While water alone is not usually considered an effective disinfectant, I cannot rule out the possibility that, under sufficiently favorable testing conditions, it might show a measurable effect on ATP test results, which is what Clean Zero seems to be basing its efficiency claims on.
Update: The material safety data sheet for Clean Zero located by grafix, if confirmed to be accurate, pretty much confirms this option.  The only substance listed in section 3 of the data sheet as being present in the product is distilled water.  If ozone, hydrogen peroxide or any other reactive substance was included in the Clean Zero solution, it would legally have to be listed on the data sheet.
(FWIW, I very much doubt they would lie about the composition of their product on the official data sheet, since doing so would attract the attention of government agencies that take that kind of stuff very seriously and open them to legal action that would be very hard for them to weasel out of — much worse than, say, making dubious marketing claims.)

You'd want acidic peroxide if you want it stable, which is a problem if you can't add "chemicals".

Is homeopathy mentioned anywhere in the literature, maybe check if any of the principals involved are or were homeopaths. Homeopathic ozone surpassingly useful at 0% concentration.

Hydrogen peroxide is very much a "chemical" though, even using marketinglish.

@Neinstein so is water. Those quacks are often pretty liberal with the use of the term "chemical". It's often used in contrast to "natural" (which is complete bs but it seems to resonate with people). Maybe they refer to "no chemicals added" because the machine makes it internally?

"You'd want acidic peroxide if you want it stable, which is a problem if you can't add chemicals"
It's also a problem if the data sheet linked below suggests a pH of 7 and documents no other substances. I assume peroxide would also cause eye irritation or mild skin irritation? Neither of which are documented on the safety sheet.

I remember that the ultra pure water in neutrino detectors is said to be corrosive, but I can't determine if it's a myth or not.

Easy way to detect if it's hydrogen peroxide: Pour it on fresh-ish blood. It reacts by producing insane quantities of bubbles. It's the best way I've found to clean blood from cloth before it stains (e.g. I cut myself, bleed on clothes or sheets before noticing, use hydrogen peroxide to get rid of most, if not all, of the blood stain immediately).

@AndreKR It can definitely eat away at some materials that a less pure water wouldnt touch.  We often run water in copper pipe, but extremely pure water will have copper leach into it from the pipes.  It's the lack of minerals/dissolved solids in pure water that causes it.  The water has a lot of capacity for things to dissolve in it, so copper migrates to the water through diffusion.

@civitas homeopathic ozone is unsurprisingly useless, you mean.

@AndreKR Water is one of the most corrosive chemicals in the Universe—an unbelievable number of substances dissolve in it.

If I had the means to create a small-scale peroxide manufacturing machine, I'd market it as such - might as well capture the hairdresser market too... Also I've noticed that the current site for the product does not really make any claims about the product having disinfectant qualities, rather that the product "absorbs dirt and contamination and leaves no surface residue" - guess what else is a really good solvent for dirt and contamination that, in its pure, filtered form, leaves no surface residue?

Why isn't it sodium hydroxide and sodium hypochlorite? I think both can be produced by electrolysis of salt water. A weak solution should be nontoxic, but a strong solution would be required to last for several months.

I like this answer, but I think the data sheet posted by grafix below (which doesn't appear to be in the public domain, but is illuminating) rules out hydrogen peroxide. I am more and more convinced it simply is distilled water.

The "chemical-free" ingredient is probably ozone (O3), a disinfectant
The first steps of the process are to filter and purify the water, including with reverse osmosis. Unfortunately, even after poring over dozens of pages about the cleaner and the devices that make it, I could not find any actual disclosure of what the "final stages" of the treatment process are. The writing has clearly been "hydro-embellished" with marketing speak and has very few solid details. Nonetheless, the following statements stand out:

It's "unstable", leaves no residue, and is also environmentally friendly
The Clean Zero 80 Cabinet, which makes the liquid, only needs a source of water (and new filters, as needed)
It's apparently more effective at cleaning than just water

It kills bacteria and viruses according to the quote in question
According to a study done by the company, it replaced "Stainless Steel Cleaner, Glass/Mirror Cleaner, General Multi- Purpose Cleaner and a Disinfectant Cleaner"


It's not hazardous to consume, though they say specifically not to
It's described as "re-engineered water"

Ozonated water seems like a solid match for this, point for point. According to Ozone Water Is an Effective Disinfectant for SARS-CoV-2:



The residual ozone in the water can be decomposed rapidly and converted to oxygen within a short period (typically within 30 min) under natural conditions. This feature is highly valuable for food disinfection.




Secondly, an ozone water generator's price is usually as low as 8,000 Yuan in China, which can convert tons of tap water into ozone water in less than 30 min. [...]

Filters are used in devices like these to filter out compounds (like bromide) that may react poorly with ozone. This is likely also the reason they emphasize the purification process and advise not mixing the cleaner with anything.

Cleaning:



Thirdly, SARS-CoV-2 can be inactivated by ozone water within 1 min, which is very efficient. In addition to ozone water, other studies also showed that ozone gas is highly effective in eliminating SARS-CoV-2.


More from The Strategist: "according to studies cited by [environmental consultant Brian] Oram, that aqueous ozone can break down a large array of bacteria, viruses, and protozoan, including E. coli and salmonella, in addition to odors and soil molecules."


Though the health benefits of doing so have been debated, it has been drunk directly and is also used as a disinfectant for food and water. See What Is Ozonated Water, and Can You Drink It?

Ozonated water is a type of "engineered water". Other types of engineered water can clearly be ruled out, like steam.



Huh. That’s actually less handwavy than I thought it would be. On the surface it sounded like utter nonsense (though IMO referring to Ozone as “chemical-free” is somewhat disingenuous) but this does seem to fit with the facts

The irony is that if this is accurate, it arguably disproves the ‘ideal for all daily cleaning tasks’ claim. Ozone is a strong oxidizer (that’s how it works for disinfection), meaning it will bleach or degrade many materials with repeated exposure. Most things you wouldn’t use chlorine bleach or hydrogen peroxide to clean are going to have the same issues with ozonated water eventually too, though it will probably take much longer for the effects to be visible.

Ozone is O₃, Hydrogen Peroxide is H₂O₂, Dihydrogen Monoxide (water) is H₂O, …, but it's totally free of chemicals?

@RayButterworth Unless it is made of dark matter, neutrinos, or other non-baryonic matter, it cannot be free of "chemicals".

Chemical-free disinfectant does exist — it's called UV radiation.

@gerrit Great! Now we just have to figure out what radioactive atom that doesn't chemically bond with anything produces UV photons when it decays...

@gerrit ... or for example very hot steam or infrared heater if you want it to be without water.

This answer seems otherwise plausible, but the relatively short (30 minutes or less) half-life of ozone in water seems incompatible with Clean Zero's assertion that "Clean Zero will remain active for a minimum of 10 months" when stored "away from direct sunlight" in a spray bottle. If Clean Zero is ozonated water, it's not going to stay ozonated for more than a few hours at best.

The sad part is that if they said "we use ozone" I would have read the ad/notice. When I read about 7-stage something and energizing something, I do not go past these lines.

Isn't ozone considered an air pollutant? Would using an ozone cleaner produce enough ozone to affect the local air quality in a space?

@nneonneo Airborne ozone is nasty, since it can also cause lung damage with enough exposure. But this isn't airborne but aqueous ozone, which has a half life of mere minutes at room temperature. I think it becomes hydroxide, but I'm not sure what happens after that.

Important point: The materials do not claim to KILL microorganisms, but to "Remove" or "Eradicate" or "Eliminate" them. In other words, it may literally just be washing them away, just like plain water would do.

Presumably, mechanical methods are chemical free by some definitions as no chemicals are reacted just abraded away which I'll call mixing stuff away (as opposed to together). The tools used of course are typically solid objects with chemical compositions.

I'm not sure, but I think distributing household products that release ozone is in violation of law in many jurisdictions.

Both standard bleach (sodium hypochlorite) and sodium hydroxide can be produced by electrolysis from salt. So the machine could just be making bleach.

The manufacturer’s data sheet suggests that Clean Zero is just distilled water.
The relevant section is "Section 3: Composition Information on Ingredients":

3.1 Chemical Characterisation: Substances

CAS No. Description 7732-18-5 water, distilled, conductivity or of similar purity
Identification number(s) EC number: 231-791-2


Those numbers are consistent with purified water. Further, physical data is quoted that tracks with pure water. However, some information is more concerning, such as "Section 4: First Aid Measures":

4.1 Description of First Aid Measures
[...]

After eye contact: Rinse opened eye for several minutes under running water.


I would posit that this is standard advice given for almost all chemicals and most likely the result of the template.

It would be helpful to quote what you feel is the relevant portion, and explain how you come to this conclusion.

Very interesting. Chemical Abstracts Service (CAS) Registry number 7732-18-5 is apparently just water, and the European Chemicals Agency number (EC) given also corresponds to just water.
I assume if it contained Ozone, they'd need to disclose CAS 10028-15-6 as being present on the data sheet and 7722-84-1 for Hydrogen Peroxide? They claim a pH of 7, but surely Hydrogen Peroxide would lower its pH?

If true, then someone should sue the mfr for false advertising. Distilled water does not have any "mechanical action when applied to surfaces".

I suspect I may not get an answer to this, but can I ask where you got this data sheet from, @grafix? The archived URL is a (now?) private Google Drive file, and searches on Google for "Trade name" "Clean Zero" "CAS number" yield no results.

@LawnmowerMan: I suspect the mechanical action comes from the "apply" rather than the water.

@MooingDuck that's fine if you're advertising a pressure washer. Not cool when you are advertising a "chemical-free surface cleaner" in a bottle. How vigorously do you have to shake the bottle to get this alleged "mechanical action"?

@LawnmowerMan: I mean that maybe the mechanical action is either the water hitting the surface, or the sponge/rag that applies it to the surface.

@MooingDuck since when has "pouring water on a surface" been considered an effective cleaning method? Who actually describes that as "mechanical action"? No reasonable person will grant that definition. "composition of Clean Zero is unstable and therefore it performs a mechanical action when applied to surfaces" That doesn't sound like a sponge doing the action to me.

@LawnmowerMan I think I understand their claim.  It's kinda what I was thinking when I first read this question, and this data sheet seems to back up my suspicion.  I'm pretty sure this is just Reverse Osmosis water, with no remineralization.  I'm not sure how strong the "mechanical action" would be, but because of the purity of the water, it should pick up chemicals from surfaces due to diffusion.  Like you shouldnt run RO water through copper pipes, because the copper leaches into the water, due to the near-zero concentration of dissolved solids, and the process of diffusion.

But that said, I dont see it being a great cleaner... It wouldnt be an instant process, and even in theory I dont think it would pick up everything.  But it fits a lot of the things they are saying.  The 99% figure seems odd, but it's possible that untreated water already gets a high %. Also, the same press release with the 99% figure also claims it's a "zero carbon product" because it can make the RO water in-situ, which doesnt follow.  It still uses power, so I dont see how they can claim that unless it's a 0 carbon emission power plant supplying electricity.  So they might just lie.

@JMac RO is just one method to obtain distilled water. However, it doesn't explain why it is "unstable" and must be used quickly. And plain water cannot leave a "streak-free surface" in the presence of oils, even if it's 100% pure. This is pretty obvious fraud.

Plain water is actually a very effective cleaning agent by itself. Simply rinsing a smooth hard surface with clean water will easily remove the majority of dust, dirt, and debris. The chemicals added to water to make cleaning agents are generally there to enhance the already effective cleaning capabilities of the water. They do little by themselves. Surfactants to improve wetting, detergents to increase solubility of insoluble soils, and antimicrobials intended to neutralize harmful organisms all rely on the water being there.

@LawnmowerMan In their description that I'm talking about, they describe using a semi-permiable membrane, it's almost certainly an RO process.   The "unstable" is presumably how it has a tendency to leech out material from what it contacts, due to diffusion and it's very low dissolved solid concentration.  I dont see anything in their documents suggesting it must be used quickly.  And even a quick google search seems to suggest pure RO water is actually commonly used for commercial window cleaning.

This discussion, while interesting, IMHO gives the produces way too much benefit of the doubt. It is a scam, short and simple.

Let's assume that the water is "chemical-free" in the sense that it contains no chemicals in addition to those normally in water. Water is normally in equilibrium with surrounding gases (air) and there is normally a gas-water interface that has significance to cleaning.  For example, trace organics which may contaminate water will tend to accumulate at the gas-water interface, and for this reason one step to produce highly pure water is to allow small bubbles to pass through it and then skim them off from the surface.
The gas-water interface is also thought to accumulate charged species, such as those normally in equilibrium with H2O (hydroxide, hydronium, etc...) or naturally present mineral salts.
I googled "nanobubble cleaning" and found this commercial site among others, and this scientific paper by a well-respected expert in the nanobubble field, which explains some of the principles.
The method of producing bubbles which last long enough for cleaning might involve electrolysis or extreme mixing, cavitation or filtration. Though these processes may introduce transient chemical species, if they are not long-lasting then it might be justified to say that the water is "chemical-free" since it would only contain what is normally in water and bubbles.

An interesting theory - but do the claims the manufacturer makes about shelf life stack up with the scientific paper you link which claims stability for only 24h?

@AdamWilliams I know nothing about the manufacturer and can't speak for their product. My post is to address the repeated comments in this thread related to the "chemical-free" aspect. Regarding the stability of nanobubbles, this is one of the most critical questions in the field, particularly regarding bulk nanobubbles. According to traditional theories they should not be stable for even seconds. Apparent observations to the contrary are what make the field interesting, and many have sought conditions in which they last longer. But verifying stability has been a major problem.

Is it Electrolyzed Oxidized (EO) Water
Apparently, if current runs through water, you can get a cleaner and a disinfectant.

EO water is created when a saltwater solution goes through an
electrolysis process, which separates the water’s positive and
negative ions. This makes two forms of water: one very acidic and one
very alkaline.

Electrified water packs powerful health punch
I had heard of them using it in hotels years ago. The workers didn't think it was any good because there were no bubbles when they sprayed it.
Electrified water lets cleaners ditch the bleach

This process produces two solutions: one with hypochlorous acid (HOCl) and other with sodium hydroxide (NaOH).

Doesn't this answer the question - How can "chemical-free" surface cleaners work?

How? The described procedure starts with a solution of sodium chloride (NaCl) and results with two solutions: hypochlorous acid (HOCl) and sodium hydroxide (NaOH). Do you think these are "chemical-free"? For details see electrolysed water on Wikipedia.
